# change date format from char

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following formats in an `indicator_date` field.  The `indicator_date` field is char data type. Is there a way to display them standardized in `mm/dd/yyyy` format when I query that column? The users are allowed to manually type the date however they choose and I cannot change that. Thanks.

Sample of how the date is displayed:

```
5/2/2018
,5/21/2018
,01/29/2018
```

I've tried `to_date(INDICATOR_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy')` but it returns an error.

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

Comment: This is why you should not be storing dates as string in the first place... If they can type in any format, how do you know if 5/2/2018 is February 5th or May 2nd? What if the string doesn't represent a day at all? If they are all actually M/D/Y, or you're assuming that, and there are no other formats like 2018-01-13, what are you actually trying to do - just put the leading zeros in for the month and day?

Comment: I know. The company I work for does not care nor does anyone know that it should be a date field. Yes a leading zero. mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: *"The users are allowed to manually type the date however they choose and I cannot change that."* - Its time to change your company!

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Only thing I can think to do is review a number of rows and see what date formats are used and build some logic to convert each type to the desired format. Then test your logic against all of the data. If some new date format comes along and it blows up then add that one to the logic. I'm not sure what else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `to_char()` and `to_date()`?

```
select to_char(to_date('5/2/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
from dual
```

Comment: `The users are allowed to manually type the date however they choose and I cannot change that` What if user typed it  as `2018-01-13`

Comment: They prob could type it in that format unfortunately. I haven't seen it but nothing would stop it.

Comment: When the users can write in what they want you have to do a best guest with a rank of the most common formats.

Comment: @smattiko84 - "Nothing would stop it" is unfortunate. Can't you at least add a check constraint to require the "free-text" string to follow one of a small number of permitted patterns, like mm/dd/yyyy, mm-dd-yyyy, mm-dd-rr?

Comment: @mathguy - i'm a nobody and don't have that power lol. Thanks everyone for looking at this but it is a lost cause until they fix the data type. I've found 8/17/20118 and 23018 for another.

Answer (score 0):

For invalid dates (year 20118) it's not possible to write a good conversion expression ... but for the rest the approach could be:

```
  with dats as (
             select '5/2/2018' dt from dual
  union all select '5/21/2018' dt from dual
  union all select '01/29/2018' dt from dual
  union all select '2018-01-13' dt from dual
  union all select '8/17/20118' dt from dual
  union all select '23018' dt from dual
  )
  select dt
  , to_char(
     case when regexp_like(dt,'(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([12][0-9]{3,3})$') then to_date(dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         when regexp_like(dt,'((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/([12][0-9]{3,3})$') then to_date(dt,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
         when regexp_like(dt,'([12][0-9]{3,3})-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$') then to_date(dt,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  --       when regexp_like(dt,'^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(([12][0-9])?[0-9]{2,2})$') then to_date(regexp_replace(dt,'^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(([12][0-9])?[0-9]{2,2})$','\1/\2/\3') ,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
  else null end   
   , 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) dtconv 
  from dats
  ;
```

Problem with 23018 was that 22818 would work but Feb 30 2018 is not existing.